# SQL query with multiple SET @

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have this code:
db.php

```
/* Database credentials. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
define('DB_SERVER', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'login');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DB_NAME', 'beta_cm');
 
/* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
 
// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

register.php

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once "php/db.php";
 
// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $username_err = "";
$username_err = $password_err = $confirm_password_err = "";
 
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
 
    // Validate username
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter a username.";
    } elseif(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/', trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Username can only contain letters, numbers, and underscores.";
    } else{
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT guid FROM users WHERE username = ?";
        
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                /* store result */
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
                
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                    $username_err = "This username is already taken.";
                } else{
                    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }
    
    // Validate password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter a password.";     
    } elseif(strlen(trim($_POST["password"])) < 6){
        $password_err = "Password must have atleast 6 characters.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }
    
    // Validate confirm password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["confirm_password"]))){
        $confirm_password_err = "Please confirm password.";     
    } else{
        $confirm_password = trim($_POST["confirm_password"]);
        if(empty($password_err) && ($password != $confirm_password)){
            $confirm_password_err = "Password did not match.";
        }
    }
    
    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err)){
        
        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)";
         
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $param_username, $param_password);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Redirect to login page
                //
                //create tables
// sql to create table
$sql = "SET @i_name :='".$username."' COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
SET @i_guid :=(select guid from users where username = @i_name) COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
SET @i_db_name := CONCAT('db_',@i_name) COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;   
SET @sql := CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ', @i_db_name,' 
(
id VARCHAR(255),
revision VARCHAR(255),
name VARCHAR(255),
type VARCHAR(255),
folder VARCHAR(255),
ip VARCHAR(255),
port VARCHAR(255),
login VARCHAR(255),
password VARCHAR(255),
deleted VARCHAR(255),
description VARCHAR(255));') COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
UPDATE users SET type = 'owner' where username = @i_name;
INSERT INTO profile (userid) VALUES (@i_guid);";
if($link->query($sql)){
    header("location: login.php");
} else{
    echo "ERROR: " . $link->error;
}
$link->close();
                // end create table
             //header("location: login.php");   
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

I get an error:
ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @i_guid=(select guid from users where username = @i_name) COLLATE utf8mb4_09' at line 2

I don't understand what it means, please help.
It works correctly through phpmyadmin

The code that causes the error is located after -  "// sql to create table"

Comment: Does the object you have created for `$link` allow you to execute multiple queries in one call to `$link->query()`?

Comment: Please include the code where you first assign a value to `$link`

Comment: Better to edit your question than put it in a comment, it makes more sense that way.

Comment: i hope its better